# How to append to file sink in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.12 and I have following simple code snippet. I would like to append some data to `D:/Sql004_ConnectFileReadAndWrite.csv` every time when I run the program.

When I run the program, I find that the data can be written only if the file doesn't exist for the first time. But I would like to append the data when I run the application again.

I would ask how to append data into the file even if the file has already existed.

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.DataTypes
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.{Csv, FileSystem, Schema}

object Sql004_ConnectFileReadAndWrite {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Sql004_ConnectFileReadAndWrite")
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val fmt = new Csv().fieldDelimiter(',').deriveSchema()
    val schema = new Schema()
      .field("a", DataTypes.STRING())
      .field("b", DataTypes.STRING())
      .field("c", DataTypes.STRING())
    val path = "D:/Sql004_ConnectFileReadAndWrite.csv"
    tenv.connect(new FileSystem().path(path)).withSchema(schema).withFormat(fmt).createTemporaryTable("sinkTable")



    val sourceStream = env.fromElements(("a", "b", "c"), ("d", "e", "f"))

    sourceStream.print()

    val table = tenv.fromDataStream(sourceStream).as("c1", "c2", "c3")
    table.executeInsert("sinkTable")
    env.execute("Sql004_ConnectFileReadAndWrite")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's filesystem abstraction does not support appending to existing files, or overwriting a portion of previously written data. This is because Flink wants to treat some object stores (e.g., S3) as filesystems that only offer eventual consistency for the operations involved.